# Negation of a void pointer Realloc

Tags: c, if-statement, realloc, negation

I was reading a C code, and I didn't understand well a line :

```
str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(*str)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
```

what does the `!str` mean ?

The code  read an input string from a user then realloc dynamically the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer in C is "falsy" if it is a null pointer, and "truthy" otherwise.

So `if (!str) return str;` means that if `str` is NULL (meaning that the allocation failed) the function returns `str` (i.e. NULL).  It could also be written as `if (str == NULL) return str;`.

Comment: Its too much clear for me right now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This if statement

```
if(!str)return str;
```

is equivalent to

```
if( str == NULL )return str;
```

or

```
if( str == 0 )return str;
```

That is it means that if the memory was not allocated (the function `realloc` returned a null pointer) then this null pointer is returned from the function that calls `realloc`.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
> equivalent to (0==E).

Instead of calling `realloc`

```
str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(*str)*size);
```

you could call the function `malloc` with the same result

```
str = malloc( sizeof( *str ) * size );
```

To indeed reallocate memory the first parameter in its call should be a non null pointer. Otherwise `realloc` behaves as `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator evaluates to 1 if its argument is equal to 0 and evaluates to 0 if it is not.

So `!str` is exactly equivalent to `str==0`, and comparing a pointer to 0 is the same as comparing it to NULL, so it is the same as `str==NULL`.

Comment: Thank you it's clear now